# C++: store/remember type of template class

Tags: c++, templates, types, casting

Let's assume we have a class like the following:

```cpp
class AbstractContainer{
    ...
};

template <typename T>
class Container : public AbstractContainer {
    T someFunction();
};
```

Now there is another class which has a member variable that shall store one of these containers. However, the template type shall not be fixed. Therefore, instead of declaring the member variable as of type `Container`, it's declared as of type `AbstractContainer*`, so a pointer at the base class. This pointer should be able to store all types of `Container` classes, regardless of the template parameter.

```cpp
class Interface{
public:
    Interface();
    void doSth();
private:
    AbstractContainer* container;
};
```

Let's assume the container is constructed in the constructor of the `Interface` class like this:

```cpp
Interface::Interface(){
    if (/* some condition */)
        this->container = new Container<int>(25);
    } else {
        this->container = new Container<float>(25);
    }
    //here I'd need to remember of which type container is: int or float
}
```

So here I'd need to somehow store of which type my container is (`int` or `float`). I know it at this point of my program and it's totally deterministic. I need to store it, because later I might have to cast my `AbstractContainer*` back to a `Container<int>*` or a `Container<float>*`, for example in another function:

```cpp
void Interface::doSth(){
    //here I have to recall what the type was
    if(/* type was int */) {
        dynamic_cast<Container<int>&>(*(this->container)).someFunction();
    } else {
        dynamic_cast<Container<float>&>(*(this->container)).someFunction();
    }
}
```

I have thought about using an `enum` that contains values for all different supported types and saving the type in an additional member variable of that enum type. Then I'd have to make a `switch` statement that checks for all the different possibilities and performs the correct cast. However, I wondered if there might not be an easier way.

What I'd basically like to do, is store the type used in the constructor of `Interface` and then recall it in `Interface::doSth`.

EDIT: I have to make clear that the function `someFunction` depends on the template parameter `T`. So it is not an option to make it virtual.

Comment: First you need to answer why `Interface::doSth` accepts `Container<int>` as well as `Container<float>`. Maybe it calculates the sum and doesn't care about the specific underlying type. In that case you write a `virtual double get_sum() const` function in `AbstractContainer` and `override` it in the various `Container<T>`. There are other ways to make it work, but throwing away the type information and then recovering it with a cast is probably the worst one.

Comment: How about it returns one of the elements of container. Then it would return an `int` for the one and a `float` for the other container.

I cannot define the function in the base class, because it requires the template parameter `T`.

Comment: `boost::variant` and `static_visitor` might be an alternative design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do

```
void Interface::doSth(){
    if (auto* c_int = dynamic_cast<Container<int>*>(this->container)) {
        c_int->someFunction();
    } else if (auto* c_float = dynamic_cast<Container<float>*>(this->container)) {
        c_float->someFunction();
    }
}
```

But why not move `someFunction()` into the base class ? and use virtual method ?

Comment: Why `auto*` instead of `auto`?

Comment: Because `someFunction` depends on the template parameter. It might e.g. have a return type of type `T`. I changed the question accordingly. I'm not really sure what you did there.

Comment: @user1488118: Should not `Interface::doSth()` be `virtual` ? So implementation doesn't require those casts. *visitor* might be also a possibility.

Comment: As I wrote before, if `Interface::doSth` requires the template parameter I cannot make it virtual, right?

Comment: @user1488118: You're right, not in your case (possible with co-variant return type).

Comment: @Jarod: could you please explain your solution to me? I'm not sure if I understand it. From what I see you are just trying the different casts. I (above) used to cast to a reference, which would result in a `std::bad_cast` exception if the type was wrong. You, however, are using pointers. From what I've read `dynamic_cast` returns a `nullptr` in this case, if the types do not match. So I suppose the if condition checks if the returned pointer is a nullptr?

Comment: @user1488118: Indeed, `dynamic_cast<T*>` returns `nullptr` when cast fails (and is tested in the if with a strange syntax). `dynamic_cast<T&>` throws when cast fails (you may use `try catch` to handle that, but it is more convenient do just test pointer).

Comment: If you could have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980157/c-class-with-template-member-variable (see accepted answer). They use an approach where they do the casting in the base class (the base class has a virtual template function). However, you still have to remember the type, to pass it as template argument. If I'd consider using this approach, would you still recommend to do as you posted in your answer? Or would that change anything?

Comment: @user1488118: it is mostly equivalent to what I posted: if you template `void doSth();`. Then you have to choose how to handle error of type. The main difference is who has to know the real Type.

Comment: I didn't want to template `doSth`. I wanted to make `someFunction` a virtual template function in `AbstractContainer`. I think the main difference would be that I'd have to call `container->someFunction<type>()` instead of `dynamic_cast<type>(...).someFunction()`. So I can't just try all possible types, unless I somehow handle it internally in the implementation of the `someFunction` function in the base class where the cast happens then.

Comment: Of course I could still use the same `if(cast) - else` construction as in your example just with the difference that I don't really need the casted pointer but would do this merely to identify the type.

Answer (score 1):

Though [Jarod42's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35767422/68304) is better, one way to do it is by using `typeid`:

```
void doSth()
{
    if (typeid(*container).hash_code() == typeid(Container<int>).hash_code())
    {
        cout << "int" << endl;
    }
    else if (typeid(*container).hash_code() == typeid(Container<float>).hash_code())
    {
        cout << "float" << endl;
    }
}
```

But you'll need at least a virtual function in the base class. You can make a virtual destructor, for example.

Answer (score 1):

May be your answer is [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

```
template<class T, template<class> class U>
class AbstractContainer
{
    void interface()
    {
        static_cast<U<T> *>(this)->implementation();
    }
};

template<class T>
class Container : public AbstractContainer<T, Container>
{
    void implementation()
    {

    }
};
```

Comment: This approach actually looks interesting. However, I think it wouldn't be helpful in my case. That is because the base class is dependent on the template parameter. The whole motivation for the inheritance was that I could store a pointer to the base class, while the actual object contained different types. For example I could have a `Container<int>` or a `Container<float>` and they all could be stored in an `AbstractContainer*`, because the base class is no template class.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
template <class T>
T doSth(Container<T> &container){
    return container.someFunction(); //assume someFunction returns a T
}
```

You don't need a base class, no inheritance, no casts.

Comment: But then I cannot store containers with different types in my `Interface` class, because I'd either have to declare `container` to be a `Container<int>` **or** a `Container<float>`

Comment: @user1488118 How about making it an `Interface<T>` or an `Interface<Container>`?

Comment: That's not an option, because in my case (which this question is a simplified version of) the Interface class is an actual user interface class (so a Qt window). I cannot simply destroy it during execution of the program. However, the content of the container should be able to change. The user has the option to read in binary files from disk. These files can contain different data types and all of them should be handled.

Comment: @user1488118 Well, you cannot use the containers if you don't know what they contain. If the files the user loads are settings files that change the state of the program you make a `virtual void apply_settings()`. If the data is supposed to be displayed by some widget you make a `virtual void load_into_widget(QWidget *)`. Since you don't know the type you cannot use it, so your use case must be able to abstract the type away. If you describe the use case more maybe I can be more concrete.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. The class `Container` itself knows its template type, and all its methods can access it. So it is able to operate on all types. I could also have a function which returns the value of one element. The Interface class of course has to know which type is stored in `Container`. And it does, because it itself constructs the container. The whole question here is how to "remember" that type, when I later have to call functions specific to the templated child class from another method of `Interface`.

Comment: You can easily remember the type with a `Type_rememberer<T>`, but that doesn't help, because you are again dependent on type `T`. So what you need to do is erase `T` from `Type_rememberer`, which is called [type erasure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089498). The easiest way to implement it is to store an `std::function` and assign a lambda such as `[&container]{ for (auto &e : container) cout << e;}`. The point that I seem to fail to bring across is that you should put the actual usage (i.e. printing) into the function instead of recovering the type and then apply the usage externally.

Answer (score 0):

```
class AbstactObject {
public:
  virtual ~AbstractObject() = 0;

  virtual AbstractObject &doSomething() = 0;
}

template<class T>
class Object : AbstactObject {
public:
  virtual ~Object();

  virtual Object<T> &doSomething();

  T &get();
private:
  T t;
}

class AbstractContainer {
public:
  virtual ~AbstractObject() = 0;

  virtual AbstractObject &doSomething();

private:
  AbstractObject *obj;
};

template<class T>
class Container : AbstactContainer {
public:
  virtual ~Container();

  virtual Object<T> &doSomething() {
    return obj->doSomething();
  };
}

class Interface {
public:
  Interface();
  void doSth();
private:
  AbstractContainer* container;
};


Interface::Interface() {
  if (/* some condition */)
    container = new Container<int>(25);
  } else {
    container = new Container<float>(25);
  }
}

void Interface::doSth() {
  auto obj = container->doSomething();
  auto val = obj.get();    
}
```

when you want to get the T value

```
auto obj = container->doSomething();
auto val = obj.get();
```

Please check: Covariant return type
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type

Comment: Please note that in your case the return of `doSomething()` is `void`. This doesn't work if the return type is `T`.

Comment: Hm...that's kind of hard to comprehend. What about `*obj`? It's never initialised.