# Is type erasure concept exist in C-language?

Tags: c, types, casting, downcast, erasure

I wonder if type erasing techniques are used anywhere in C language.
What happens in C, when type casting is done? Does it use concepts similar to type erasure and down casting?

**What are the main difference between type erasure and type casting?**

Comment: C doesn't have any latent types, so there's nothing to erase.

Comment: Here is a [`C++` question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089498/type-erasure-for-methods-with-differing-in-return-types) FYI.

Comment: What is the main difference between type erasure and casting?

Comment: @NaveeNeo They're totally different concepts. Type erasure refers to whether the type information exists in the runtime data. C data doesn't have type information. Casting is converting an object from one type to another.

Comment: It is a technique to implement generic code.  Far, far removed from what C can do.  I suppose *typedef* could qualify somewhat.  Eh, you'll have to have a lot of imagination.  Let it run, run, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you a Java developer? 
If yes you need to forget a LOT of things and learn another LOT.

Down casting means inheritance. So this is not C.

C can cast almost anything to anything (C assumes that you know what you are doing, contrary to Java, C# and others)

Type erasure is a Java concept because JRE doesn't have generics at run-time, only raw-types.

In C you have only binary code at run-time, just like in Assembly and that's all we need to have lightning-fast executables (remember that almost any compiler, framework or virtual machine is built in C or C++).

In C there is no such thing of RTTI (Run-Time Type Information) and we don't need this because the aim of C is program directly over the metal.